# php pdo code to calculate next 6 month date from selected date

Tags: php, mysql, date, pdo

my form has two textbox ok

`coupon ,startingdate,`

data entered in coupon textbox like  501,502,503,504,505,506. 
datatype - varchar

startingdate is a date picker -
datatype - datetime

now what i need is **if my coupontextbox has 6 value**s and i select current date in date picker then **it insert 6 date with +1 month in every date.**

**for ex** - **my textbox has  501,502,503,504,505,506 total 6 values. and i select 13-02-2015 in datepicker and click save**

**then it create 6 dates like below and insert in coupondate column.**

plz suggest how to do this...

```
501-   13-03-2015,

502-   13-04-2015,

503-   13-05-2015,

504-   13-06-2015,

505-   13-07-2015  

506 -  13-08-2015
```

below is my code

**coupondate  datatype - varchar** because we need to insert all date values in same column in comma exploded form

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['save']))
{
$coupon = $_POST['coupon']; 
$startingdate = $_POST['startingdate'];
$coupondate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($startingdate) . " +1 month");
$insertrow = $database->insertRow("INSERT INTO receipt_entry (coupondate,coupon,startingdate)                       
VALUES  (:coupondate,:coupon,:startingdate)",                       
array(':coupondate'=>$coupondate,':coupon'=>$coupon,':startingdate'=>$startingdate))
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$coupon       = '501,502,503,504,505,506';
$startingdate = '13-02-2015';

// Replace:
//    $coupondate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($startingdate) . " +1 month");
// with:
$coupons = explode(',', $coupon);

$dates = Array();
for ($no = 1; $no < count($coupons) + 1; $no++) {
    $dates[] = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($startingdate . " +" . $no . " MONTHS -1 DAYS"));
}

$coupondate = implode(',', $dates);

// Test output
echo $coupondate, PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
12-03-2015,12-04-2015,12-05-2015,12-06-2015,12-07-2015,12-08-2015
```

Comment: every thing is working properly but plz tell  me  if i need output like 12-03-2015,12-04-2015 so what we change in code... I need output of selected date - 1 day. for ex if i select 13-02-2015 then it generate 12-03-2015,12-04-2015,12-05-2015,12-06-2015  like wise....

Comment: Good to hear. Too bad though you actually did not mark my answer as the accepted one... :-P

Comment: sory sir,i accepted another solution by mistake and click on it.very very sorry,now i accept your solution and again thanks.

Comment: No problem mate! Thanks for fixing it and good luck on you coupon project :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use `DateTime` for this instead of the time functions.

```
$coupon       = '501,502,503,504,505,506';
$startingdate = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', '13-02-2015');
$coupondate = clone $startingdate;
$coupons = explode(',', $coupon);
$interval = new DateInterval('P1M');
$params = array(
   ':coupon' => $coupon,
   // i assume this is an actual date column and will need to 
   // in SQL date format
   ':startingdate' => $startingdate->format('Y-m-d'),
   ':coupondate' => array()
);

foreach ($coupon as $k => $coupon) {

   // add 1 month to the previous coupondate
   $coupondate->add($interval);
   $params['coupon'][] = $coupondate->format('d-m-Y');       
}

// implode out dates to a comma sep list
$params[':coupondate'] = implode(',', $params[':coupondate']);

$database->insertRow("INSERT INTO receipt_entry (coupondate,coupon,startingdate) VALUES  (:coupondate,:coupon,:startingdate)", $params);
```